# Multi module Maven project or separate repositories?

Tags: git, repository, modules, maven

Consider the following architecture:

- Application A
- Application B
- Commons-Util

A and B share a lot of functionality. That's why we plan to extract the shared code into a commons library.

I am aware of the advantages and disadvantages of multi modules vs. separate repositories.
However, I'm not sure for what to go in this specific case.

- A and B should be releaseable and deployable separately (+ separete repos)
- A and B should always depend on the same Commons-Util library (+ multi module). Therefore, dependency management should be at a central place (+ multi module).
- Team A and Team B should be independant (+ separate repos)
- No other projects besides A and B are using Commons-Util (+ multi module)

What's the best solution in this case?

Comment: If A and B share a lot of functionality they will not be independent. Depending on the details they may need to coordinate updates and releases for compatibility.

Comment: So if you have two teams, who is responsible for the Commons-Util?

Comment: A little late but, if you use an artifact repository like Sonatype Nexus or JFrog Artifactory, the problem goes away and your decision can be based on preference rather than necessity. (If the decision were up to me, I'd go with an artifact repository and separate repos.  If you don't use an artifact repository, you're almost forced to go multi-module)